# General error: 1 near ")": syntax error") in Laravel 5.6.33

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, sqlite

I have some problem with Laravel Migrations .
I have a many to many relationship between my articles and tags .
'article_tag' Migration :

```
Schema::create('article_tag', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->integer('article_id')->unsigned()->index();
    $table->foreign('article_id')->refrences('id')->on('tags')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
    $table->integer('tag_id')->unsigned()->index();
    $table->foreign('tag_id')->refrences('id')->on('articles')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
});
```

'tags' Migration :

```
Schema::create('tags', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

'article Migration :

```
Schema::create('articles', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('title');
    $table->text('body');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

My Console Log :

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error:
>   1 near ")": syntax error (SQL: create table "article_tag"
>   ("article_id" integer not null, "tag_id" integer not null, foreign
>   key("article_id") references "tags"() on delete cascade on update
>   cascade, foreign key("tag_id") references "articles"() on delete
>   cascade on update cascade)

Exception trace:

> 1   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 near ")":
>   syntax error")
>         /home/user/Desktop/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:452
>
> 2   PDO::prepare("create table "article_tag" ("article_id" integer
>   not null, "tag_id" integer not null, foreign key("article_id")
>   references "tags"() on delete cascade on update cascade, foreign
>   key("tag_id") references "articles"() on delete cascade on update
>   cascade)")
>         /home/user/Desktop/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:452

Best , Javad

Comment: Did you copy the examples, directly from your code, you have a typo in references, for your foreigns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a misspelling in your migration. You are saying that `refrences->()` but it should be `references->()`

```
Schema::create('article_tag', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('article_id')->unsigned()->index();
// in here
        $table->foreign('article_id')->refrences('id')->on('tags')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
        $table->integer('tag_id')->unsigned()->index();
// and in here too
        $table->foreign('tag_id')->refrences('id')->on('articles')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
    });
```

Comment: Don't be sorry, EVERYbody makes these mistakes.